# when change mSwitch1 or mSwitch2 or mSwitch3, change All Switchs?

Tags: javascript, android, switch-statement

Why if change mSwitch1 or mSwitch2 or mSwitch3, change All Switchs? If you leave one Switch in Activity, everything works.

AndroidStudio / javascript .
Why if change mSwitch1 or mSwitch2 or mSwitch3, change All Switchs? If you leave one Switch in Activity, everything works.

```js
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);

...
String sw1 = pref.getString(APP_PREFERENCES_SWITCH1, "");
        String sw2 = pref.getString(APP_PREFERENCES_SWITCH2, "");
        String sw3 = pref.getString(APP_PREFERENCES_SWITCH3, "");
        if (sw1.length() == 2) {
            mSwitch1.setChecked(true);
        }
        if (sw1.length() == 1) {
            mSwitch1.setChecked(false);
        }
        if (sw2.length() == 2) {
            mSwitch2.setChecked(true);
        }
        if (sw2.length() == 1) {
            mSwitch2.setChecked(false);
        }
        if (sw3.length() == 2) {
            mSwitch3.setChecked(true);
        }
        if (sw3.length() == 1) {
            mSwitch3.setChecked(false);
        }

...

 mSwitch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                
                SharedPreferences pref3 = getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
                if (mSwitch1.isChecked()) {
                    String Swe1 = "12";
                    Editor editSwe1 = pref3.edit();
                    editSwe1.putString(APP_PREFERENCES_SWITCH1, Swe1);
                    editSwe1.apply();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SET ON1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    String Swe2 = "1";
                    Editor editSwe2 = pref3.edit();
                    editSwe2.putString(APP_PREFERENCES_SWITCH1, Swe2);
                    editSwe2.apply();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SET OFF1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

mSwitch2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
           
            SharedPreferences pref4 = getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
            if (mSwitch2.isChecked()) {
                String Swe3 = "12";
                Editor editSwe3 = pref4.edit();
                editSwe3.putString(APP_PREFERENCES_SWITCH2, Swe3);
                editSwe3.apply();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SET ON2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                String Swe4 = "1";
                Editor editSwe4 = pref4.edit();
                editSwe4.putString(APP_PREFERENCES_SWITCH2, Swe4);
                editSwe4.apply();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SET OFF2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

...
}
```

Comment: it is hard to understand question what is the problem are you saying that when select any one switch then same applied for same?

Comment: "it is hard to understand question what is the problem are you saying that when select any one switch then same applied for same?" Yes, for all other!

Comment: check the key name of APP_PREFERENCES_SWITCH2 , APP_PREFERENCES_SWITCH1 etc.

Comment: "check the key name of APP_PREFERENCES_SWITCH2 , APP_PREFERENCES_SWITCH1 etc."    If change One switch , change all key all switches (equally, parallel), why?

Comment: this all key name must be different to store different value

Comment: "Pavan". Many thanks! I didn't know subtleties SharedPreferences(keys). Two days of headaches.